# JBoss shutdown takes forever

Tags: jboss, quartz-scheduler, shutdown

I am having issues in stopping the jboss. Most of the times the when I execute the shutdown. it stops the server in couple of seconds.

But some times it takes forver to stop and I have to kill the process.

Whenerver the shut down takes long I see the scheduler was running and in logs  I see

```
2014-07-14 19:19:29,124 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean] (JBoss Shutdown Hook) Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2014-07-14 19:19:29,124 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (JBoss Shutdown Hook) Scheduler scheduler_$_s608203at1vl07shutting down.
2014-07-14 19:19:29,124 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (JBoss Shutdown Hook) Scheduler scheduler_$_s608203at1vl07 paused.
```

and nothing after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Quartz scheduler thread and all threads in its thread pool are marked as daemon threads so that they do not to prevent the JVM from exiting.

This can be achieved by setting the following Quartz properties respectively:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true

org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons=true
```

While it is safe to mark the scheduler thread as a daemon thread, you should think before you mark your thread pool threads as daemons threads, because when the JVM exits, these "worker" threads can be in the middle of executing some logic that you do not want to abort abruptly. If that is the case, you can have your jobs implement the `org.quartz.InterruptableJob` interface and implement a JVM shutdown hook somewhere in your application that interrupts all currently executing jobs (the list of which can be obtained from the `org.quartz.Scheduler` API).